Is there any chance get out of bad policies plan as I have opted previously from LIC?
I opted a policy from LIC during college days with my part time salary. However, the maturity amount turned out to be less than expected. Currently, I am considering opting for a new policy and want to switch to a different one. Is there any possibility to transfer or close my previous policy while retaining all benefits, or can I transfer the entire amount to the new policy I am considering?

I edited the tags assuming you're talking about life insurance in India - please adjust the tags if this is not the case.

I'm also assuming India because this seems to be about Whole Life, and most of the rest of the world has concluded that that is a bad option.

Yes from a pesonal finance insurance and investment must not be combined. You can check for surrender clauses in life insurance policy and surrender the policy. You cannot transfer benefits to a new policy. Take help of a CA in India.
